# How to set date in html (input type date) and javascript with conditions?

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting today's date in the pickup date column using html and js.
html

```
<label for="inputState" class="form-label">Date</label>
<input type="date" id="PickUpDate" class="form-select">
```

js

```
<script>
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
        }

        PickUpDate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        document.getElementById("PickUpDate").setAttribute("min", PickUpDate);
    </script>
```

I want to create another field **DropOffDate** and take input from the user. But I want to enable dates after 2 days of pickupdate. How can I implement that using html and javascript.
I am using this in a asp.net core application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=datepicker+days+after+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing that you were trying to implement? Set the initial state of the `dropoffdate` element and then assign an event listener to the pickup element - when there is a change you edit the dropoff value and attributes as per your needs.

```js
const pad=function(i) {
    return ( parseInt(i)<10 ) ? '0' + parseInt(i) : parseInt(i);
};

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();




PickUpDate = yyyy + '-' + pad(mm) + '-' + pad(dd);
document.getElementById("PickUpDate").setAttribute("min", PickUpDate);

// set initial minimum date for dropoff
DropOffDate = yyyy + '-' + pad(mm) + '-' + pad( dd + 2 );
document.getElementById("DropOffDate").setAttribute("min", DropOffDate);


// add event listener to the pickup - change properties & value of droppoff
// when this changes.
document.getElementById("PickUpDate").addEventListener('change',function(e){
  let dropoff=new Date( this.value );
      dropoff.setDate( dropoff.getDate() + 2 );
  
  dropoff=[ dropoff.getFullYear(), pad( dropoff.getMonth() + 1 ), pad( dropoff.getDate() ) ].join('-');

  let input=document.getElementById("DropOffDate");
      input.setAttribute('min', dropoff );
      input.value=dropoff;
});
```

```css
label{display:block;padding:0.25rem;margin:1rem;width:50%;}
label input{float:right}
```

```html
<label for="inputState" class="form-label">
  Pick-Up Date
  <input type="date" id="PickUpDate" class="form-select" />
</label>

<label for="inputState" class="form-label">
  Drop-Off Date
  <input type="date" id="DropOffDate" class="form-select" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the `min` attribute on date change, for example

```js
const pickUpDate = document.getElementById('pickUpDate'),
  dropOffDate = document.getElementById('dropOffDate');

pickUpDate.onchange = function() {
  const date = this.valueAsDate;
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);
  dropOffDate.min = date.getFullYear().toString() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, 0) + '-' + date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, 0);
};
```

```html
<input type="date" id="pickUpDate" />
<input type="date" id="dropOffDate" />
```